# Alarm does not work when phone is in deeply asleep

Tags: android

I have an Alarm App that works perfectly 
except when the phone is deeply asleep. 
When truly asleep my alarm activity shows up *after* the user wakes up the phone. I want the phone to wake up the user...

The app starts my AlarmAcivity directly from a BroadcastReceiver. (Not from a Service.)

One clue:
Log D **DeepSleepService**:  AlarmManager go out of deepsleep
...

PowerManagerService: putReleasedWakeLock
PowerManagerService: ******mAcquiredLocks contents*****
PowerManagerService: LockList entry : flags=0x10000006 tag=com.solidllc.foo.WakeLock
PowerManagerService: LockList entry : flags=0x1 tag=RILJ
PowerManagerService: LockList entry : flags=0x1 tag=*network-location*
PowerManagerService: LockList entry : flags=0xa tag=KEEP_SCREEN_ON_FLAG
PowerManagerService: putReleasedWakeLock --> remove partial wakelocks into list, size i
...

//
//My manifest:
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.DEVICE_POWER
android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD

The Alarm Clock that comes with Android has the above plus: "Modify global system settings" and "Retrieve Running apps".

Anyone know what can be done?

Thanks much.

Here is the code that sets the alarm:

```
void armAlarm(int hour, int minute) {

    Calendar alarmtime = new GregorianCalendar();

    alarmtime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    alarmtime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    alarmtime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(RatActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(RatActivity.this, 0,
            intent, 0);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.cancel(pi);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmtime.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
}
```

Comment: Please consider posting the source code where you are scheduling the alarm.

Comment: Deep sleep mode is available only on some devices (e.g. Archos tablet), and there it also warns user when enabled: "Nothing will work in deep sleep, including alarms".  Ordinary Android phones use soft sleep (suspend) mode.

Comment: Thanks much. I just tested the built in alarm and it does not work either (good) when the device is in deep sleep. (On the "Phone options" menu you can pick "Sleep" which puts a Moto Droid in deep sleep.) The original problem I'm trying to solve is that my alarm does not go off when the phone has been idle for a long time; such as a whole night. How can I get the phone into this (soft sleep?) mode quickly so I can debug it?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was wrong with my code: In was accessing a database in the  BroadcastReceiver. 
This is a bad/wrong (as the documentation states). 
 The fact that it only shows up after a long sleep just makes the bug harder to find.

Comment: Pls link to and/or quote the documentation for this ;)